# How to get the screen coordinate of a control in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use the following line in code behind to get the position of some control on the screen:

```
double coordinate = (double)MyControl.PointFromScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)).X;
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in XAML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML - get user control position relative to whole window as binding property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060685/xaml-get-user-control-position-relative-to-whole-window-as-binding-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the absolute position of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387449/how-to-get-the-absolute-position-of-an-element)